# Slider to show different canvas shapes at specific values

Tags: canvas, slider, shapes

I want to have a canvas shape as a background ("rectangle") and above that different canvas shapes (e.g "circle" and "square"), which should show up when the slider reaches a specific value.

I found the way to show different images with the jQuery slider, but is it also possible to show different canvas shapes instead of images with that slider and how?

**here are the canvas shapes**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="rectangle" width="240" height="440" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="circle" width="240" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 2;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="square" width="240" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>

    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('rectangle');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(20, 20, 200, 400);
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fill();

      var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 80;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();

      var canvas = document.getElementById('square');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(40, 40, 160, 160);
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fill();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**and here the slider with changing images**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slider demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>#slider { margin: 10px; }  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
      var img1 = $('<img\>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
      var img2 = $('<img\>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200/');
      var foto = $('#div1');

      foto.html(img1);

      $("#slider").slider({
          slide: function(event, ui) {
              if (ui.value > 50) {
                  $('#div1').html(img2);
              } else {
                  $('#div1').html(img1);
              }
          }
      });
  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. You simple need to mix the code and change how each object is displayed (instead of changing an src) [**like this**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/qq9bur7n)!

The Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('rectangle');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(20, 20, 200, 400);
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fill();

    var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 80;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();

    var canvas = document.getElementById('square');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(40, 40, 160, 160);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fill();

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var shape1 = $('#rectangle');
      var shape2 = $('#circle');
      var shape3 = $('#square');
      shape1.css({'display':'block'});
      shape2.css({'display':'none'});
      shape3.css({'display':'none'});

      $("#slider").slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          if (ui.value > 66) {
            shape2.css({'display':'none'});
            shape3.css({'display':'block'});
          } 
          else if(ui.value > 33) {
            shape1.css({'display':'none'});
            shape2.css({'display':'block'});
            shape3.css({'display':'none'});
          }
          else {
            shape1.css({'display':'block'});
            shape2.css({'display':'none'});
          }
        }
      });
    });
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="rectangle" width="240" height="440" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="circle" width="240" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 2;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="square" width="240" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your link works perfectly, but when I take your code and try it out, it won't work. Do I miss something?

Comment: Fixed by adding `window.onload = function {` then the js. See the edit, you should be able to copy and paste it